# Excluding visibility to only one subsite for an AD user

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sub-site

[image: Intranet]

I am trying to exclude visibility for my user, UserKiosk, to ONLY the 'KIOSK' subsite.  The issue I am having is that, since UserKiosk is an AD user they are automatically part of the 'Everyone' Sharepoint group.  This group has been added to the Intranet Visitors which grants view/read access to all of the other subsites as well.  When, UserKiosk, logs into the Intranet they are able to see the other subsites (Home, Our Company, OUr benefits, etc.) and access them but cannot edit.  I do not want this, I only want them to see Kiosk.  Is this possible or would I have to create a totally separate site/site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to move KIOSK to a different site collection on a different web application and then add a Policy to deny access to the original web application or delete the group everyone and replace it with one that doesn't have kiosk inside.

Comment: I was afraid someone might say that.  I was hoping their was another way.  Would it be possible to remove the 'Everyone' group in Sharepoint and just create groups in AD and then add users to the appropriate groups and then use the AD groups in Sharepoint permissions?  This way I would not put the UserKiosk in a group so they would only have access to what I assign them.  Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, you can use AD groups. In fact, 100% of the places I've worked used this as policy. You can configure AD sync and then whenever you want to grant permissions SharePoint will pull the AD groups.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I will definitely look into this and coordinate with our AD person, as this seems to be our best option.  I am sure down the road we will have more requests to give a user or group of users access to a portion of the Intranet but not all of it